# Parsing unexpected types in JSON with GSON

Tags: android, json, gson

I have several classes of objects which need to be parsed inside of an android application, which I am already handling quite easily thanks to GSON. However I have just come across a scenario which calls for something more complex and despite the amount of reading and experimenting I've done I have been unable to solve.

Here's a slimmed down example of one of the classes I am using to parse:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public String id;
    public List<String> details;
    public Locations locations;
    public List<Timing> timing;
    public Image image;

    public class Locations {
       public List<Location> destinations;
       public List<Location> past;
    }

    public class Timing {
       public String start;
       public String end;
    }
}
```

Then I have another class which contains this class:

```
public class ResultObject
{
    //These represent the possible return values for a result object.
    public Location location;
    public List<MyClass> myClass;
    public List<OtherClass> otherClass;
}
```

These are very simple versions of my classes, anyway the JSON version of the ResultObject comes from the server and is easily parsed like so:

```
Type mapType = new TypeToken<ResultObject>(){}.getType();
result = gson.fromJson(httpResult.stream, mapType);
```

This works great, I get my nicely parsed objects all day long. The problem arises when I receive an unexpected type on any field inside any of the hierarchy of classes it causes the entire JSON parse to fail and therefore the result is null. For example the 'locations.past' may end up coming back as an array of Strings rather than full JSON objects like they are supposed to be, and instead of just that array list being empty, the entire ResultObject is forfeit to the parsing error. I would really like a way around this, which I suspect lies in using a custom deserializer, but no examples even touch a hierarchy like this.

If anyone has a good idea of how to handle unexpected types when parsing objects of this size I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Why is your source JSON varying? It would seem to me you ***want*** the parse to error out if you get JSON in an unexpected format.

Comment: The reason for this is that this response is coming from a server using mongodb as a datastore. The locations objects are stored as objectIds and are being populated on the server side for some calls, while on others they are not. On side note when they are not it would be nice to have the string version of the objectId in the array so I can go get that manually from the server, but I will settle even for null items if it means no more parsing failures.

Comment: Ah, MongoDB. So your object schemas can even change, depending on version. I think your options are to have a normalization step on your server side to transform the JSON into a standard format, or do custom serialization on the client side. Even [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) would have problems with varying format (though it handles missing and unknown properties ***very*** well).

Comment: I figured custom deserialization would have to be where this is going, but I'd really like to keep it as object oriented as possible so we don't have to modify our deserializers any time we modify a class.

Comment: If you have a small set of possible variations, you can deserialize the JSON into temporary key-value data structure (JSONObject), test for a particular variation, normalize the object, then deserialize into a strong type. More work, but at least you retain the majority of the OOP nature of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest getting rid of the inner class definitions.  If there is some namespace concern, then use nested static classes.  Serializing and deserializing with Gson will be simpler.